# Formatting issue related to data type

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are a number of $- symbols of general type.[image]

[image]

Converted to currency type if that can help run sum function. But still showing #VALUE error. Is there a way this $- can be removed from all the columns by one command/formula. Removing $- one-by-one manually is the last option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the
[SUMIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b),
for example:

```
 =SUMIF(H1:H14,"<>$-")
```

For more information see
[Sum if cells are not equal to](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-cells-are-not-equal-to).

Comment: I have replaced all $- with 0.

Comment: Did you import your data from somewhere? (or copy/paste from another application). This is the second question you have asked about this type of data. My suspicion is that, if you have imported the data from somewhere, it is the import process that is causing the cells to be imported as text rather than the numeric data you clearly want it to be.